# Amazon like refined filtering in solr

Tags: solr, faceted-search

We need to implement drill down search like Amazon.

[image]

If any supplier is selected then,
currently it disabled rest of suppliers as solr facet only returns that selected filter.
query: `supplier:supplierId`

Though above query retuns multiple `Screen Color`/`Screen Size`, but on further selection, only the selected element is returned per filter section.

Any help to make it work like Amazon.com 's refined filtering will be much appreciated.

Comment: you mean you want to be able to select several facet filters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To provide multi-select faceting, you need to tag the filter involved so that you can exclude it when faceting on the corresponding field. This can be achieved using both the `tag` and `ex` [local parameters](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/local-parameters-in-queries.html).

Solr Ref Guide - [Tagging and Excluding Filters](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/faceting.html#Faceting-TaggingandExcludingFilters) :

> To implement a multi-select facet for a given field, a GUI may want to still
>   display the other field values and their associated counts, as if
>   the corresponding filter constraint had not yet been applied.
>
> To return counts for the field values that are currently not selected,
>   tag filters that directly constrain the field, and exclude those
>   filters when faceting on it.

For example, for a query that would originally look like :

```
q=mainquery&fq=supplier:supplierId&facet=true&facet.field=supplier
```

You would do the following :

```
q=mainquery&fq={!tag=sup}supplier:supplierId&facet=true&facet.field={!ex=sup}supplier
```